# HIbernate: select multiple distinct columns resulting in error

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to perform a query

```
Hibernate: select distinct this_.platform as y0_, this_.device as y1_, this_.date as y2_ from my_lab this_ where this_.brand=? and this_.network=?
```

using the code:

```
    Criteria crit = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(Lab.class);

    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();

    if (platform == null) {
        projList.add(Projections.property("platform"));
    } else {

        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("platform", platform));
    }

    if (device == null) {
        projList.add(Projections.property("device"));
    } else {

        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("device", device));
    }

    if (date == null) {
        projList.add(Projections.property("date"));
    } else {
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("date", dateOfVideo));
    }

    if (brand == null) {
        projList.add(Projections.property("brand"));
    } else {
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("brand", brand));
    }


    if (network == null) {
        projList.add(Projections.property("network"));
    } else {
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("network", network));
    }

    crit.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));

    List<String> list = crit.list();
    return list;
```

But when I call this service, it gives me following error:

```
 "Could not write content: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String",
```

Unable to understand why. Have mentioned `produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}` in the get request as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the line

```
List<String> list = crit.list();
```

Actually with multiple projections you should expect `List<Object>` and access the values like this

```
List<Object> rows = crit.list();
for(Object r: rows){
  Object[] row = (Object[]) r;
}
```